# .htaccess rewrite googlebot and other search engine crawlers

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to create .htaccess file in my public_html folder that will recognize googlebot and few other crawlers in the moment they want to crawler my web site and to rewrite - using .htaccess    on Apache http server-to give googlebot same name files from another location example mywebsite.com rewrite from mywebsite.com/perica directory index.html and all site web pages.
The reason I want to do so is because of using a lot of Javascript and I want to create html snapshouts that will be place in that directory for googlebot (so I don't have to think can he read javascript or not...).
I have found code below somewhere on web and I interesting:
   1. Is the syntax good? Is there something else it should be write in .htaccess file (I never work with it before). 
   2. Is there something else I should do - writing some additional code in my html pages, or creating something else...?
   3. How to include yahoo crawler too?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Googlebot.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Bingbot.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Baiduspider.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*iaskspider.*
RewriteRule .* http://mywebsite.com/perica/$1 [P]
```

Will it work and what  $1 at the end of line means?

Comment: What you intend to do would be seen as [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355) by Google and others, and could lead to the site being dropped from their listings.

Comment: Cloaking as I see is cheating what I want to do is my Javascript accessibly by googlebot. Googlebot is machine you have to simplifid html pages for it or googlebot won't understand it.

Comment: If you are registered with [Google Webmasters](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) it gives you access to a tool which shows you how Googlebot "sees" the page. It will process some Javascript. I suspect other search engines will also process Javascript, if only to keep up with Google.

Comment: I em  registered with Google Webmasters and that part how googlebot sees the page with javascript is a bit suspicious... In the part web ans then success it shows html with javascript as it is "writen" not with it result when executed. And I think that they just show you what google web browser chrome do not really googlebot....